# 1 switch handling several servers or several switches handling a server each?

Tags: switch

Which of those two approaches are better for a more stable network? I was thinking 1 switch handling several servers so that other switches are able to handle other devices such as a desktop PC or laptops

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your Idea is correct, but the concept is broader. There are two type of Traffic in Network.

- East/West Traffic
- North/South Traffic

East/West Traffic is traffic between servers. It is separate traffic and it should be in more secure environment. In standard data centers, separate firewalls are also used. In a network diagram, we depict it horizontally. Data Center switches (Cisco Nexus, etc.) are specialized in handling East/West traffic.

North/South Traffic is server to client (or Data Center to outside) traffic. It should be separated from East/West Traffic. In a network diagram, North/South Traffic depicted vertically.

In addition to that, servers and LAN should not be on same network (subnet) as well. You need to configure separate VLAN(s) for servers, otherwise if you handle your data center traffic in a separate switch, it will be useless.

For more details [click here](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/east-west-traffic).

Comment: "if you handle your data center traffic in a separate switch, it will be useless" - not necessarily. Ethernet can be pretty efficient in handling traffic flows unless the broadcast domain becomes too large or traffic patterns become too complex for the fabric.

Comment: @Zac67 what i mean on this, if our servers and client machine on same subnet it is not secure. Although we handle servers on separate switch